# Tensorflow tutorial error in first step: "Cannot import name 'keras'"

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am new to Python and am trying to learn Tensorflow. I installed Tensorflow yesterday (so it should be updated) via a new environment on Anaconda. The first step in the Tensorflow tutorial is:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
```

The result I am getting is:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-3d1e6d42ad48> in <module>
      1 import tensorflow as tf
----> 2 from tensorflow import keras

ImportError: cannot import name 'keras'
```

How do I get keras to work so I can start the tutorial?

Computer is Windows 10.

I looked through stackoverflow and saw similar questions, but not this specific one. 
I do not know the version because when I do:

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.version)
```

I get:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-7380a45e29ab> in <module>
      1 import tensorflow as tf
----> 2 print(tf.version)

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'version'
```

Comment: try `tf.__version__` or `tf.VERSION`

Comment: Thanks for the contribution. However, I got the same error in both versions your recommended :/

Comment: Are u using notebook? If so, then u didn't install Jupiter in the environment u have tensor flow.

Comment: I am using Jupyter through Anaconda. I launched Jupyter through the Anaconda Navigator in my TensorFlow environment. I am putting all the code into a Jupyter notebook.

Comment: U need to install Jupiter in the tensor flow environment. Within the terminal with tensor flow environment activated, Use `conda install jupyter` and then launch the notebook. U should be ok then, because it appears now Jupiter is being launched from the base environment.

Comment: Good suggestion, but it does not seem to work. I launched Jupyter through the Anaconda Navigator and it is definitely through the tensorflow environment. (Up top in the Home section is says "Applications on tensorflow.env" and I launched Jupyter from there. Also, I activated the tensorflow environment via the command window and did ```conda install jupyter```.  It did download packages including jupyter, but I am still getting the same errors.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the navigator, but Did u disconnect and connect again to notebook after installed jupyter

Comment: Yes, I completely exited from Anaconda and reopened it after installing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps I took:

downloaded jupyter to my tensorflow environment

updated some packages

downloaded matplotlib to the tensorflow environment.

It seems to be working now. Thank you to the team effort to help a noob!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to import tensorflow from keras. You actually don't even need to import tensorflow. Keras uses tensorflow as backend by default.

You can do for example:

```
import keras as k
```

Although this is not recommended, as you will be importing the whole library. So you generally would only import the packages you need. For instance:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
```

If you want to access tensorflow from keras you can do:

```
import keras.backend as K
```

And then you can access tensorflow's methods from `K`

Comment: Arguably OP refers to Keras as part of Tensorflow, and not the stand-alone version: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I tried both options, and for both of them I got "Using TensorFlow backend." in red followed by a bunch of code that ended with ```ImportError: cannot import name 'ops'```

Answer (score 0):

Once check the version of Python that you are using.

In the anaconda prompt type `python --version` and check it. If it shows 3.7.0, then tensorflow won't work since python 3.7 doesn't support tensorflow as of now.

In that case, you have to create a new environment in anaconda and install a version of python that supports tensorflow (like Python 3.6). You can follow this [link](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-python.html) for the same.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. When I downloaded TensorFlow the command window automatically asked if I wanted Python to be downgraded from 3.7.1 to 3.6.8, which I allowed it to do.